# Strange results: Absolute value vs. square root of square in integral computations

Tags: numerical-integration

Today I encountered a phenomenon in the free online version of WolframAlpha which looks to me like a bug. It would be great if someone could check whether the phenomenon also occurs when using Mathematica directly. I am not sure whether it might actually be normal behavior and I am just using  the software incorrectly.

**Edit 1: As it was asked in the comments, the code I entered in WolframAlpha can be seen by clicking on the links to WolframAlpha provided below.**

**Edit 2: In the comment bbgodfrey observed that Mathematica gives the same answers (with a slow convergence warning), which shows that the issue is not WolframAlpha specific but comes from the underlying Mathematica computer algebra system.**

**I would also like to point out that I am not asking a mathematical question, I am just pointing out that replacing an absolute value by "square root of square" changes the result of a computation in a way that shouldn't happen.**

I am considering the integral
$$I(a):=\int_{\mathbb R}\int_{\mathbb R}\frac{|1-xy|^{a-1}}{((1+x^2)(1+y^2))^{(a+1)/2}}\,\mathrm{d}x\, \mathrm{d} y$$
for $a\geq 1$.

The free WolframAlpha is able to compute $I(a)$ for some $a$, for example, for $a=16$ one gets [this result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20%20%28%281%2Bx%5E2%29%281%2By%5E2%29%29%5E%28-%2816%2B1%29%2F2%29abs%281-xy%29%5E%2816-1%29%20dx%20dy%20from%20x%3D-infty%20to%20infty%2C%20y%3D-infty%20to%20infty), which claims that
$$I(16)=1.9141.$$
If one replaces `abs(1-xy)^(a-1)` in the input by an artificial `((1-xy)^2)((a-1)/2)`, then one obtains a [different result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20%20%28%281%2Bx%5E2%29%281%2By%5E2%29%29%5E%28-%2816%2B1%29%2F2%29%28%281-xy%29%5E2%29%5E%28%2816-1%29%2F2%29%20dx%20dy%20from%20x%3D-infty%20to%20infty%2C%20y%3D-infty%20to%20infty), namely
$$I(16)=1.99968.$$
Now, one might think that the difference is simply explained by the fact that WolframAlpha cancels the powers and in reality computes the integral $I(a)$ with `abs(1-xy)^(a-1)` replaced by `(1-xy)^(a-1)` but this is not the case: For the latter integral one gets a third, [different value](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%20%20%28%281%2Bx%5E2%29%281%2By%5E2%29%29%5E%28-%2816%2B1%29%2F2%29%281-xy%29%5E%2816-1%29%20dx%20dy%20from%20x%3D-infty%20to%20infty%2C%20y%3D-infty%20to%20infty).

What strikes me is that **the correct result for $I(16)$ seems to be the one where

`((1-xy)^2)((a-1)/2)` is used**, i.e., $I(16)=1.99968$.

Indeed, using basic Lie theoretic tools one can prove that
$$I(a)=\frac{1}{4}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}|\cos(x-y)|^{a-1}\,\mathrm{d}x\, \mathrm{d} y,$$
and WolframAlpha computes the value $I(16)=1.99968$ for the latter integral regardless of whether one writes `abs(cos(x-y))^(a-1)` or `(cos(x-y)^2)^((a-1)/2)` in the input. See [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%201%2F4%20%7Ccos%28x-y%29%7C%5E%2816-1%29%20dx%20dy%20from%20x%3D0%20to%202pi%2C%20y%3D0%20to%202pi) and [here](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate%201%2F4%20%28cos%28x-y%29%5E2%29%5E%28%2816-1%29%2F2%29%20dx%20dy%20from%20x%3D0%20to%202pi%2C%20y%3D0%20to%202pi).

**Is this a bug?**

The value $a=16$ is not important here, I just picked a value where WolframAlpha actually computes a result both with `abs(1-xy)^(a-1)`
and `((1-xy)^2)((a-1)/2)`.
Whenever that is the case for an even value of $a$, the phenomenon occurs.

When $a$ is odd, so that the absolute value does not matter, WolframAlpha always computes the same value of $I(a)$ in all variants of the input.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Have you run this calculation with Mathematica?  If so, please provide the code and result in your question.

Comment: @bbgodfrey: I don't have Mathematica, which is why I used the free WolframAlpha website. The code I entered there is visible by clicking on the links I provided.

Comment: You can use the Wolfram Language for free (with some resource limitations) on the [Wolfram Cloud](https://www.wolframcloud.com/).

Comment: Seems to be a question about mathematics, for math.stackexchange.com, not about coding in Mathematica.  Or a question about W|A, for community.wolfram.com, not for here. (W|A questions are explicitly [off-topic](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).)

Comment: I just ran the two cases on Mathematica 12.3 and obtained the same answers.  However, the first computation also issued an error message that "Numerical integration converging too slowly".

Comment: @MichaelE2: The fact that bbgodfrey obtained the same answers in Mathematica shows that the issue is not W|A specific but comes from the underlying Mathematica computer algebra system. I am not asking a mathematical question, I am just pointing out that replacing an absolute value by "square root of square" changes the computation result, which in my opinion it shouldn't.

Comment: It would be better to point it out to WRI....

Comment: `Block[{a = 16},
 NIntegrate[
  Abs[1 - x y]^(a - 1)/((1 + x^2) (1 + y^2))^((a + 1)/
      2), {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
  Exclusions -> x y == 1]
 ]` gives the claimed correct answer. I don't see an issue, except an ordinary one with numerical integral with singular loci..

Comment: `Block[{a = 16},
 NIntegrate[
  Abs[1 - x y]^(a - 1)/((1 + x^2) (1 + y^2))^((a + 1)/
      2), {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}, 
  WorkingPrecision -> 32, PrecisionGoal -> 8, 
  Method -> {"GaussKronrodRule"}, MaxRecursion -> 9]
 ]` also gives the correct answer.  Lowering working precision to `WorkingPrecision -> 16` confirms it probably is a numerics issue with the default singularity handler.

Comment: The clue for me was that I didn't think that $1.91$ and $1.99$ seemed very different.

Comment: @MichaelE2: Thank you, that's interesting! Do you have an idea why there is a difference between using `abs(1-xy)` and `sqrt((1-xy)^2)` ? In the latter case the numerical problem seems to be absent.

Comment: My guess it's how the perceived singularity due to `Abs[]` is handled. Off hand I don't know the algorithm. Here's a way to get the wrong $1.9141$ answer from the sqrt-squared integral: `Block[{a=16}, NIntegrate[((1 - x y)^2)^((a - 1)/2)/((1 + x^2) (1 + y^2))^((a + 1)/2), {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, {y, -Infinity, 1/x, Infinity}]]` — Turn off singularity handling & get the right answer with `Abs[]`: `Block[{a=16}, NIntegrate[Abs[1 - x y]^(a - 1)/((1 + x^2) (1 + y^2))^((a + 1)/2), {x, -Infinity, Infinity}, {y, -Infinity, Infinity}, Method -> {"GlobalAdaptive", "SymbolicProcessing" -> None}]]`